# Testing web applications in 64-bit Internet Explorer is only supported on Internet Explorer versions 10 or later

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have a problem running CodedUI tests though Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate) and hoping someone is able to help me out. I’m totally lost.

I’m currently working on a Windows 2008 R2 machine (64 bit).  For creating CodedUI tests  I’m using Visual Studio 2012. I’ve installed all latest updates, including Internet Explorer version 10.

When running a CodedUI testen in Visual Studio 2012  I get the following error message :

*TechnologyNotSupportedExeption was unhandled by user code. Testing web applications in 64-bit Internet Explorer is only supported on Internet Explorer versions 10 or later.*

Probably the problem is that the CodedUI tests should automatically be running in IE 10, 32 bit. But it seems that automatically IE 64 bit is used to execute the tests.
The following things I tried, but didn’t solve the problem:

- I installed all latest Microsoft updates
- I did a downgrade to IE 9 and a reinstall of IE 10
- Adjusted the properties of de CodedUI testproject: Platform target =
  x86
- Added a testsetting file to my CodedUI project and changed Hosts/Run
  tests in    32 bit of 64 bit process into: Force tests to run in 32
  bit process.
- Test/Test settings/Default Processor Architecture  = X86

The following steps didn't work eather:

- -Click on Start and go to Default Programs.
- Click on Associate a file type or protocol always open in a specific program.
- Browse to all the extensions where internet explorer is set as default and then click on change.
- Now Click on browse and then go to location C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe and select it.
- Click Ok and then Close. f. Click Save.

Does anyone have some ideas? I’m pretty hopeless…

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Registry value TabProcGrowth is not = 0. 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth=1